# RoomDb Query Returning null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am querying my room database to check if an item exists, however the query always returns null even though the item is already in the DB. I am using coroutines

This is my query

```
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cart_item WHERE productId = :productId)")
    suspend fun getItemCount(productId: Int): Int?
```

The function in my repository

```
 suspend fun getCartItemCount(productId: Int): Int? {
        return coroutineScope{
            cartItemDao.getItemCount(productId)
        }
    }
```

In my view model

```
fun getCartItemCount(productId: Int): MutableLiveData<Int>? {
        var itemCount: MutableLiveData<Int>? = MutableLiveData()
        launch {
            itemCount!!.value = repository.getCartItemCount(productId)
        }

        return itemCount
    }
```

And this is how i implement it in my Fragment

```
   fun getCartItemCount(productId: Int){
        var itemCount: Int? = null

       mainViewModel!!.getCartItemCount(productId)!!.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
           itemCount = it
       })
        Log.d("ITEMCOUNT ----> ", " $itemCount")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing some fundamentals on how to use coroutines.

1. Your database query is a suspend method that will execute and "*suspend*" tge execution until it returns.
2. Since your repository function is still **suspend**, you can live it up to the user on which scope to run.
3. Then we have the LiveData issue, you log the `itemCount` while still null. The trigger never did, and even if it does, it won't execute your log statement.
4. Your view model uses `LiveData` to post changes, then we do you need to return a value on your method?

   - Actual problem lies in waiting for the result synchronously, which is not.

**Suggested Changes**

Repository

```
// repository
suspend fun getCartItemCount(productId: Int): Int? {
   return cartItemDao.getItemCount(productId)

}
```

View Model

```
var itemCount: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

// maybe rename method as it's not a getter anymore
fun getCartItemCount(productId: Int) {
  viewModelScope {
    itemCount.value = repository.getCartItemCount(productId)
  }
}
```

In your fragment

```
fun getCartItemCount(productId: Int){
  mainViewModel?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    itemCount = it
    // this will be triggered every time the "LiveData.value" changes
    // this could return null if the live data value is not set.
    Log.d("ITEMCOUNT", "$it")
  })
  mainViewModel?.getCartItemCount(productId)
}
```

**Suggested Reading:**

- https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html